# Get and combine data from tables postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm Nubie.
I want to create a postgresql table by drawing data from several tables

Table1

```
| partner_id | **project_id** | partner_fund | partner_date |
| 12345      | 099            | 12345.70     | 2003-02-02   |
```

Table2

```
| partner_id | partner_name
| 12345      | monster.inc
```

Table3

```
| **package_id** | **project_id** |
| 099a           | 099            |
```

Table4

```
| **package_id** | project_name
| 099a           | kill some one
```

*package_id is corresponding to project_id

I want to make a table like this :

```
| (if)partner_id | (get)partner_name | (if)project_id (corresponding to package_id)| (get)project_name | partner_fund | partner_date
```

So, if first row shows partner_id, next column shows partner_name, etc. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the [tour] and visit the [help]. What have you tried, do you have some code that produces an error or incorrect results? Please include it if you do. I'd also suggest finding either a postgresql-specific tutorial, or a generic SQL one. There's an official [one](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/tutorial.html), in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table from a SELECT query using [`CREATE TABLE ... AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT
    table1.partner_id,
    table2.partner_name,
    table3.project_id,
    table3.project_name,
    table1.partner_fund
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.partner_id = table2.partner_id)
INNER JOIN table3 ON (table1.project_id = table3.project_id)
;
```

...and then you can also add a primary key to the new table, e.g.:

```sql
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (partner_id, project_id);
```

**Query after updated question:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT
    table1.partner_id,
    table2.partner_name,
    table1.project_id,
    table4.project_name,
    table1.partner_fund,
    table1.partner_date
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.partner_id = table2.partner_id)
INNER JOIN table3 ON (table1.project_id = table3.project_id)
INNER JOIN table4 ON (table3.package_id = table4.package_id)
;
```

Comment: This fix sir. Great. But can I revise my question please?

Comment: Please fix my revision sir.

Comment: Updated, but with your new structure, you might get duplicates due to the many-to-many on `project_id` to `project_name`.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much bro. Duplicate must be happen in project_name because partner_name is difference. Once again thanks so much

Comment: But how to define if partner_name only regist for project name?

Comment: What do you mean by "regist"?

Comment: if partner_id include the project